# set permission to folder and file both

Tags: php, laravel, file-permissions, laravel-storage

I am uploading file via `sftp` to remote server with `client_name` as dir. and `file_name` as file inside the directory.

Also I need to set `0755` permission to both the directory and file.

But currently only the file permission is set to `0755` and folder is still with `0744` permission.

```
$remote_path = $clientName . '/' . $fileNameToStore;
$ftp = Storage::disk('sftp')->put($remote_path, fopen($uploadedFile, 'r+'), 'public');
```

Here `clientName` is `dir` and `fileNameToStore` is file inside.

Comment: give the permission via terminal.

Comment: @kmgkumar these folders are created dynamically at run time

Comment: once you give permission in the parent directory, then it grants permission in child directory automatically.

Comment: If parents directory have 744 you can't set 755 to child directory.

Comment: @kmgkumar I tried. The folders that were already there when setting the parent permission all got 777 but others that were created later got the same 744.

Comment: @Azima okay, let's create the folder using corePHP mkdir("folder_path", 0755);